# DatabaseManager and connection in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am posting here to get a code review on my DatabaseManager and DatabaseConnection classes, and for answers on how I can improve. I won't spend too long drolling on, but this is a database manager that uses MySQL and creates a new DatabaseConnection for each operation.

Database Manager -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Scratch.Application.System.Database
{
    sealed class DatabaseManager
    {
        private string _host;
        private string _username;
        private string _password;
        private string _database;
        private uint _port;
        private uint _maxConnections;

        private string _connectionString;

        private DatabaseConnection _dbCon;

        public void Load()
        {
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder cs = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                ConnectionLifeTime = (60 * 5),
                ConnectionTimeout = 30,
                Database = this._database,
                DefaultCommandTimeout = 120,
                Logging = false,
                MaximumPoolSize = this._maxConnections,
                MinimumPoolSize = 3,
                Password = this._password,
                Pooling = true,
                Port = this._port,
                Server = this._host,
                UseCompression = false,
                UserID = this._username,
            };

            this._connectionString = cs.ToString();
            this._dbCon = new DatabaseConnection(this._connectionString);
        }

        public DatabaseConnection GenerateNewConnection()
        {
            // NEW connection each time...
            return new DatabaseConnection(this._connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseConnection -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Scratch.Application.System.Database
{
    class DatabaseConnection : IDisposable
    {
        private MySqlConnection _connection;
        private MySqlCommand _command;
        private DateTime _startTime;
        private List<MySqlParameter> _params;
        private MySqlTransaction _transaction;

        public DatabaseConnection(string ConnectionString)
        {
            this._connection = new MySqlConnection();
            this._connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            this._command = this._connection.CreateCommand();
            this._params = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        }

        public void OpenConnection()
        {
            if (this._connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("MySQL connection has already been opened.");
            else
                this._connection.Open(); //open the connection

            this._startTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public bool ConnectionOpen()
        {
            return this._connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
        }

        public void RegisterParameter(string param, object value)
        {
            this._params.Add(new MySqlParameter(param, value));
        }

        public MySqlDataReader ExecuteReader()
        {
            if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0)
            {
                this._command.Parameters.AddRange(this._params.ToArray());
            }

            try
            {
                return this._command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                Scratch.GetEnvironment().GetLog().Write("error", "MySQL Error: " + e.Source);
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                this._command.CommandText = string.Empty;
                this._command.Parameters.Clear();

                if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0) { this._params.Clear(); }
            }
        }

        public string GetString()
        {
            if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0)
            {
                this._command.Parameters.AddRange(this._params.ToArray());
            }

            try
            {
                return Convert.ToString(this._command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                Scratch.GetEnvironment().GetLog().WriteLine("error", "MySql Error: " + e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                this._command.CommandText = string.Empty;
                this._command.Parameters.Clear();

                if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0) { this._params.Clear(); }
            }
        }

        public void AssignQuery(string Command)
        {
            this._command.CommandText = Command;
        }

        public DataSet ExecuteDataSet()
        {
            if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0)
            {
                this._command.Parameters.AddRange(this._params.ToArray());
            }

            DataSet Set = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(this._command))
                {
                    Adapter.Fill(Set);
                }

                return Set;
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                Scratch.GetEnvironment().GetLog().WriteLine("error", "MySql Error: " + e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                this._command.CommandText = string.Empty;
                this._command.Parameters.Clear();

                if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0) { this._params.Clear(); }
            }
        }

        public DataTable ExecuteTable()
        {
            DataSet DataSet = this.ExecuteDataSet();
            return DataSet.Tables.Count > 0 ? DataSet.Tables[0] : null;
        }

        public DataRow ExecuteRow()
        {
            DataTable DataTable = this.ExecuteTable();
            return DataTable.Rows.Count > 0 ? DataTable.Rows[0] : null;
        }

        public int ExecuteNonQuery()
        {
            try
            {
                if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0)
                    this._command.Parameters.AddRange(this._params.ToArray());

                return this._command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (MySqlException exception)
            {
                Scratch.GetEnvironment().GetLog().WriteLine("error", "MySql Error: " + exception.Message);
                throw exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                this._command.CommandText = string.Empty;
                this._command.Parameters.Clear();

                if (this._params != null && this._params.Count > 0)
                    this._params.Clear();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this._connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                this._connection.Close();
                this._connection = null;
            }

            if (this._params != null)
            {
                this._params.Clear();
                this._params = null;
            }

            if (this._transaction != null)
            {
                this._transaction.Dispose();
                this._transaction = null;
            }

            if (this._command != null)
            {
                this._command.Dispose();
                this._command = null;
            }

            int Finish = (DateTime.Now - this._startTime).Milliseconds;

            if (Scratch.Debugging)
                Scratch.GetEnvironment().GetLog().Write("debug", "Query completed in " + Finish + "ms");

            if (Finish >= 5000)
                Scratch.GetEnvironment().GetLog().Write("warn", "Query took 5 seconds or longer");

            //this._poolReturn.PutObject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's `DatabaseManager`'s constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing terribly major, but:

- Use StyleCop.
- Put your `using`s on the inside of your namespace.
- Don't prefix your private members with underscores.
- Trim out dead code (i.e. `//this._poolReturn.PutObject(this);`) or leave a comment as to why it might be re-introduced in the future.
- Never `throw e`. Just `throw`.
- Add more specific information to your logs - for instance, instead of saying "five seconds or longer", add the actual execution time.
- Make a constant TimeSpan instead of duplicating your 'five seconds'.
- Subtract DateTime objects and compare to a TimeSpan, instead of converting to milliseconds.
- Add XML docs.
- Don't capitalize local variables.
- Port is not a uint, it's a ushort.
- You might want to consider database connection pooling instead of "new every time".

Comment: You say don't prefix private members with underscores - I thought this was  generally accepted? Please advise @Reinderien

Comment: @NRKirby: From what I read, StyleCop by default disallows the use of underscores, and generally I agree that they do nothing but make a mess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450238/to-underscore-or-to-not-to-underscore-that-is-the-question

The IDE, autocomplete, etc. - all of the tooling - already has a great understanding of private members, and it isn't all that useful for you to add more metadata about member protection than what's already formally there.

Comment: Using an underscore is a preference. The opinion in that old thread is 50/50 and any new topics on that matter will show you it's down to what you like. Resharper advocates underscore usage as `this` produces code smells.

Comment: You don't really need 'this' either, IMO. Anyway, as you say, it's personal preference; not important.